# Unwanted color appears in CSS gradient.. only affects Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I just noticed this little glitch in my CSS, but the only browser that has trouble with it is Chrome.

The glitch is the flat grey color that appears on the left side of my `#box`

I made a JSFiddle to duplicate the error :

http://jsfiddle.net/mar6E/

I would like the gradient to be white (`#ffffff`), and then at the last 92% fade to `#f4f4f4` then `#dddddd`.

This works fine until I add that image in there, and then set the position of the image to `10px 17px`.

I guess Chrome positions the background gradient as opposed to all the other browsers.

Any workarounds / suggestions greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any difference between Chrome and Firefox, compare this http://jsfiddle.net/mar6E/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle and in your code, you forgot to set the position that you talk about.

But my paranormal powers let me guess that you had:

```
#box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url(http://braidio.com/images/icon-dashboard.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 80%, #f4f4f4 92%, #dddddd 100%);
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-position: 10px 17px;
}
```

When you should have had:

```
#box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url(http://braidio.com/images/icon-dashboard.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 80%, #f4f4f4 92%, #dddddd 100%);
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-position: 10px 17px, 0px 0px;
}
```

If you set only a background position, it affects the 2 backgrounds ...

Comment: Paranormal powers FTW! THANK YOU!

Comment: Happy that it helped. And paranormal activity is easier when we could be neighbors.